# angularjs: directive breaks expression and data-ng-show?

Tags: angularjs, expression, directive

My html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <div in-tags text="{{ tags }}"></div>
        <div data-ng-show="tags.length" in-tags text="{{ tags }}"></div>
        <p data-ng-show="tags.length">another text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And js:

```
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.tags = 'one two three';
    })
    .directive( 'inTags',function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                text: '@'
            },
            template: '<span ng-repeat="item in text | splitByWords"> {{ item }} </span>'
        };
    })
    .filter( 'splitByWords', function() {
        return function( text ) {
            return text.split( /\s+/ );
        };
    });
```

How it works: http://jsfiddle.net/3HT2F/12/

**Question is**: Why tags.length interpreted like *false* with directive?

**extra question**: How can i hide div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your primary question, the `scope` attribute on your directive (`inTags`) sets a new isolated scope with only one member (the connected `text` attribute).  It's one of the stumbling blocks of Angular with nested scopes and isolated scopes.  When you set a literal object for the scope and specify a mapping (such as this case with at the dom attribute binding using '@'), it creates an isolated scope that doesn't inherit any other values from its parent.  So `tags` is no longer a member of the local scope on that element.

See the [scope rules for directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Second question, why wouldn't `ngShow` or `ngHide` work?  If you're on a new enough Angular (1.2+), you can also use `ngIf` to complete remove elements vs just hiding them.

Edit: Here's your [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/KaPYR/2/)